# How to check a column consecutively with a condition in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I have a large dataset, part of which is:

```
 Hours<- c(1:14)   
 Measure<- c(5,4,5,5,4,5,5,6,7,6,5,4,5,5)
 log6<- data.frame (Hours, Measure)
```

1. I would like to read 3 consecutive rows and check if log6$Measure<=5 in all 3 rows.
2. Then add another column with True or False based on the previous condition.

Expected Output:

```
   Hours Measure Result
1      1       5    -
2      2       4    -
3      3       5   TRUE
4      4       5   TRUE
5      5       4   TRUE
6      6       5   TRUE
7      7       5   TRUE
8      8       6  FALSE
9      9       7  FALSE
10    10       6  FALSE
11    11       5  FALSE
12    12       4  FALSE
13    13       5   TRUE
14    14       5   TRUE
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For reference, you can also do `c(NA, NA, rowSums(embed(log6$Measure, 3) <= 5) == 3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `rollapply` from `library(zoo)`

```
library(zoo)
log6$Result <- rollapply(log6$Measure, 3, FUN= 
         function(x) all(x<=5), fill=NA, align="right")
log6$Result
#[1]    NA    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

A variant suggested by @jogo

```
!!(rollapply(data=(log6$Measure < 6), width=3, FUN=prod, 
              by=1, fill=NA, align="right"))
```

and another:

```
rollapply(log6$Meassure < 6, 3, all, fill=NA, align="right")
```

Or from @nicola

```
rollmax(log6$Measure,3, fill=NA, align="right") <=5
```

Comment: Consider also `rollmax`: `rollmax(...)<=5`.

Comment: @nicola THanks, that is a nice suggestion.  Wouldn't it go as a separate post for you?

Comment: a variant: `rollapply(data=(log6$Meassure < 6), width=3, FUN=prod, by=1, fill=NA, align="right")` or `rollapply(log6$Meassure < 6, 3, all, fill=NA, align="right")`

Comment: I guess that if you edit the post including my suggestion it can get more attention. It's basically the same way to solve the issue (same package, same family of functions), so I don't think it deserves a separate answer.